# Adjusting weight of a body of water by substituting part of it with a lighter liquid

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, volume

As a heavily simplified example of my problem:

- Water weighs 1 gram per ML
- Alcohol weighs 0.5 gram per ML (not true of course, but humour me)

I have 100mls of water, so this has a weight of 100grams

I want to adjust the weight to 90grams by pouring out some water and substituting it with alcohol. I still want the final volume to be exactly 100mls.

I've wracked my brain on this, I feel like I need to go back to high school. Please show me the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a single variable problem: the volume $x$ of water to be replaced with alcohol. The question is, what is the mass of the resulting $100$ mLs of liquid?

The initial mass was $100$g.

You remove $x$ grams ($x$ mL) of water, the mass is now $100-x$.

You add $0.5x$ grams ($x$ mL) of alcohol, the mass is now $100-x+0.5x=100-0.5x$.

So you need to solve $100-0.5x=90$.